# Python - How to Check Point in a Polygon?

Tags: python

Below is my coding to check whether a point does exist in a polygon, but the result is False, could you help me?

```
# Importing Libraries   
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

# Opening the Vector Map
shp_path = "ADMINISTRASIDESA.shp"

# read your shapefile
r = shapefile.Reader(shp_path)

# get the shapes
shapes = r.shapes()

# build a shapely polygon from your shape
polygon = shape(shapes[0])
print(polygon)
# result :
# POLYGON ((106.701396169 -6.34824620099992, 106.7015891380001 -6.349042349999891, 
# 106.701707619 -6.349551940999955, 106.701828711 -6.350008714999912, ... ))

def checkpo(lon, lat):
    # build a shapely point from your geopoint
    point = Point(lon, lat)

    # the contains function does exactly what you want
    return polygon.contains(point)

mygeolon = 106.701396169
mygeolat = -6.34824620099992

print(checkpo(mygeolon, mygeolat))
# why result = False ???

# create point
point = Point(mygeolon,mygeolat)

# check if polygon contains point
print(polygon.contains(point))
# why result = False ???

# check if a point is in the polygon
print(point.within(polygon))
# why result = False ???
```

I already set the longitude and latitude that listed in the polygon,
but when it is checked, it returns False ???
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to Shapely documentation :

> object.contains(other)
> Returns True if no points of other lie in the exterior of the object and at least one point of the interior of other lies in the interior of object.
> (...)
> **A line’s endpoints are part of its boundary and are therefore not contained.**

What you need is `object.covers`.

> Returns True if every point of other is a point **on the interior or boundary** of
> object. This is similar to object.contains(other) except that this
> does not require any interior points of other to lie in the interior
> of object.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html